# How do I change Sublime Text 3 user config directory?

Tags: sublimetext3

Sublime Text 3 user configuration directory is, by default, at:

> ~/.config/sublime-text-3/

I would like to change it to somewhere else. Is it possible? The workaround I've done so far is to create the above directory as a symbolic link pointing to the folder I want, but it doesn't seem right. Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks for your attention in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been one year and no answer, so I'll describe what I've been doing, so I can close this topic. The best way to deal with it is by creating a symbolic link, as I mentioned before. The second way to do this is by editing Sublime's code, what I didn't figure out completly how to do, but I know it's possible. If someone knows a better solution, please post in the comments. This topic is being closed now.